# Is it possible to check which stream is used by the command? (bash)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I have an irritating problem: redirecting stderr does not work. I get:

```
iptables: Chain already exists
```

I can't be bothered to check if a chain exists already (pointless, iptables just throws an error if the chain exists before I flush it in the next step, so why bother checking if it already exists). In order to ignore this, I redirect stderr to /dev/null but this does not seem to work.

In general: how do I:

1. check which stream is used by a command in bash? is this even possible?
2. redirect ALL streams output by a command?

Comment: Yikes! layman error: i was redirecting stderr before redirecting stdout:

iptables -N droplist 2>&1 >/dev/null
iptables: Chain already exists

iptables uses stderr on error, "iptables -N droplist >/dev/null 2>&1" works. Nevertheless, the questions still stand I think.

Comment: You might be interested in "netstat -tnlp"

Answer (score 0):

- what is your iptables command?
- you can look at /proc/`<pid>`/fd/ ! there are "pipe" entries with a pid of another command involved in the command chain
- redirecting all streams in bash according to TFM:

  There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
  `&>word`
  and
  `>&word`
  Of the two forms, the first is preferred.  This is semantically equivalent to
  `>word 2>&1`

hth
Regards
Stefan K.